# Compiling C code that uses both R and numpy on Linux

Tags: python, c, r, numpy

I have some C code that uses both numpy and R. On Windows, it compiles with MSVC to a .dll which can be dynamically loaded from R and passes all the tests. However, I fail to make it work on Debian.

To investigate the problem I created the following minimal-ish example:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

SEXP main() {
   Py_Initialize();
   import_array();

   SEXP one = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, 1));
   INTEGER(one)[0] = 1;
   npy_intp dims[1] = {1};
   int data[1] = {1};
   PyObject *another = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_INT, data);

   Rprintf("Hello, %d ", INTEGER(one)[0] + *(int*)PyArray_DATA(another));
   PyRun_SimpleString("print('worlds')");

   UNPROTECT(1);
   return one;
}
```

I can compile it with

```
cl /I "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.0\include" /I "C:\Python34\include" /I "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" /c hello.c
link /dll /export:main hello.obj Rdll.lib C:/Python34/libs/python34.lib
```

where `Rdll.lib` was created from `%R_HOME%\bin\x64\R.dll` with

```
pexports R.dll > R.exp
link /lib /def:R.exp /machine:x64 /out:Rdll.lib
```

Then it can be used from R:

```
> dyn.load(paste0("hello", .Platform$dynlib.ext))
> .Call("main")
Hello, 2 worlds
[1] 1
```

When, however, I compile it on Debian with

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -lpython2.6 -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR hello.c -o hello.so
```

and import it from R the following happens:

```
> dyn.load("hello.so")
> .Call("main")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/__init__.py", line 132, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x4, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

It does produce segmentation faults unless everything related to numpy is commented out. Interacting with pure Python from R seems to be OK. But as soon as `import_array()` is called there is a segfault. I added `-I/usr/share/pyshared/numpy/core/include/` out of desperation and it didn't change anything.

Finally, if I compile the following (similar to the previous, but slightly changed) code

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

int main() {
   char *localArgs[] = {"R", "--silent"};
   Rf_initEmbeddedR(2, localArgs);
   Py_Initialize();
   import_array();

   SEXP one = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, 1));
   INTEGER(one)[0] = 1;
   npy_intp dims[1] = {1};
   int data[1] = {1};
   PyObject *another = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_INT, data);

   Rprintf("Hello, %d ", INTEGER(one)[0] + *(int*)PyArray_DATA(another));
   PyRun_SimpleString("print('worlds')");

   UNPROTECT(1);
}
```

on the same Debian machine with

```
 gcc -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/include/python2.6 -lpython2.6 -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR hello.c -o hello
```

and call it with

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/R/lib R_HOME=/usr/lib64/R ./hello
```

it suddenly doesn't crash, works well and produces "Hello, 2 worlds", as expected.

The versions are:
Windows: Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64, Python 3.4.4, numpy 1.9.3, R 3.2.0
Debian: gcc version 4.4.5 (target: x68_64-linux-gnu), Python 2.6.6, numpy 1.4.1, R 3.2.1

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** Tested on Ubuntu with both Python 3.2 and Python 2.7 with both gcc and clang. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that works (with this example as well as with the real code) is to load libpythonX.Y.so with dlopen:

```
 #include <Python.h>
 #include <Rinternals.h>
 #include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

 #ifndef _WIN32
 #include <dlfcn.h>
 #endif

 SEXP main() {
 #ifndef _WIN32
    dlopen("libpython2.6.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
 #endif
    Py_Initialize();
    import_array();

    SEXP one = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, 1));
    INTEGER(one)[0] = 1;
    npy_intp dims[1] = {1};
    int data[1] = {1};
    PyObject *another = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_INT, data);

    Rprintf("Hello, %d ", INTEGER(one)[0] + *(int*)PyArray_DATA(another));
    PyRun_SimpleString("print('worlds')");

    UNPROTECT(1);
    return one;
}
```

I do not, however, fully understand why it is needed.